# Static Table Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having some trouble with a fixed table header. On scroll it needs to become fixed and follow the table until it has passed.

Which works...

But, the cloned fixed header th widths are all wrong and knocking the layout off, you will see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/93g2etfj/2/

Any ideas would be great!

HTML:

```
<div class="section group mb-margin">
                <div class="col span_12_of_12">
                    <div class="panel table-panel">     
                        <table class="table-full">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Reference No.</th>
                                    <th>Quote Date</th>
                                    <th>Pickup</th>
                                    <th>Journey Date</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>673-727-2744</td>
                                    <td>28 Jan 2018</td>
                                    <td>London WC2H</td>
                                    <td>08 Aug 2018</td>
                                    <td>63</td>
                                    <td class="row-status row-green">Completed</td>
                                    <td class="edit-row"><a href="#"><div></div></a></td>
                                    <td class="delete-row"><div>&mdash;</div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>673-727-2744</td>
                                    <td>28 Jan 2018</td>
                                    <td>London WC2H</td>
                                    <td>08 Aug 2018</td>
                                    <td>63</td>
                                    <td class="row-status row-orange">Quoted</td>
                                    <td class="edit-row"><a href="#"><div></div></a></td>
                                    <td class="delete-row"><div>&mdash;</div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>673-727-2744</td>
                                    <td>28 Jan 2018</td>
                                    <td>London WC2H</td>
                                    <td>08 Aug 2018</td>
                                    <td>63</td>
                                    <td class="row-status row-blue">On Hold</td>
                                    <td class="edit-row"><div></div></td>
                                    <td class="delete-row"><div>&mdash;</div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>673-727-2744</td>
                                    <td>28 Jan 2018</td>
                                    <td>London WC2H</td>
                                    <td>08 Aug 2018</td>
                                    <td>63</td>
                                    <td class="row-status row-red">Cancelled</td>
                                    <td class="edit-row"><div></div></td>
                                    <td class="delete-row"><div>&mdash;</div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>673-727-2744</td>
                                    <td>28 Jan 2018</td>
                                    <td>London WC2H</td>
                                    <td>08 Aug 2018</td>
                                    <td>63</td>
                                    <td class="row-status row-green">Completed</td>
                                    <td class="edit-row"><a href="#"><div></div></a></td>
                                    <td class="delete-row"><div>&mdash;</div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>673-727-2744</td>
                                    <td>28 Jan 2018</td>
                                    <td>London WC2H</td>
                                    <td>08 Aug 2018</td>
                                    <td>63</td>
                                    <td class="row-status row-blue">On Hold</td>
                                    <td class="edit-row"><div></div></td>
                                    <td class="delete-row"><div>&mdash;</div></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>673-727-2744</td>
                                    <td>28 Jan 2018</td>
                                    <td>London WC2H</td>
                                    <td>08 Aug 2018</td>
                                    <td>63</td>
                                    <td class="row-status row-grey">Failed</td>
                                    <td class="edit-row"><div></div></td>
                                    <td class="delete-row"><div>&mdash;</div></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!-- Close table-->
                    </div>
                    <!-- Close .panel-->
                </div>
                <!-- Close .col-->
            </div>
            <!-- Close .group-->
```

CSS

```
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  margin: 0% 0 0% 3%;
}

.mb-margin {
    margin-bottom:60px;
}

.panel {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background: $white;
    border: 1px solid #CFD5E6;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 2px 0 rgba(214,221,226,0.51);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 2px 0 rgba(214,221,226,0.51);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 2px 0 rgba(214,221,226,0.51);
    @include border-radius(5px);
}

.table-panel {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
/* FULL TABLE STYLING */
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

.table-full {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.table-full thead th {
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: left!important;

    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: $darker;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.table-full tbody td {
    border: solid 1px grey;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:25px;

    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: $dark;
    letter-spacing: 0;

    &:first-child {
        font-family: arial;  
    }
}

.table-full tbody tr {
    background-color: white;
    @include transition(all,.10s);
    cursor:pointer;

    &:hover {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}

.table-full tbody td {
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}

.fixed-table-wrap {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    padding:0px;
}

.fixed{
    top:0;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
    border:none;
    background:white;
    border-bottom: solid 1px grey;
}
```

JS:

```
;(function($) {
           $.fn.fixMe = function() {
              return this.each(function() {
                 var $this = $(this),
                    $t_fixed;
                 function init() {
                    $this.wrap('<div class="fixed-table-wrap" />');
                    $t_fixed = $this.clone();
                    $t_fixed.find("tbody").remove().end().addClass("fixed").insertBefore($this);
                    resizeFixed();
                 }
                 function resizeFixed() {
                    $t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
                       $(this).css("width",$this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth()+"px");
                    });
                 }
                 function scrollFixed() {
                    var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
                    tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
                    tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
                    if(offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom)
                       $t_fixed.hide();
                    else if(offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
                       $t_fixed.show();
                 }
                 $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
                 $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
                 init();
              });
           };
        })(jQuery);

        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("table").fixMe();
           $(".up").click(function() {
              $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: 0
           }, 2000);
         });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read about `position:sticky` [here](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/), which does exactly what you want. It isn't implemented everywhere yet, but as you can see [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) it is available on 86.41% of  all devices.

Demo:

```css
dt {
  background: #B8C1C8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #989EA4;
  border-top: 1px solid #717D85;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 0 0 12px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <dl>
    <dt>A</dt>
    <dd>Andrew W.K.</dd>
    <dd>Apparat</dd>
    <dd>Arcade Fire</dd>
    <dd>At The Drive-In</dd>
    <dd>Aziz Ansari</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>C</dt>
    <dd>Chromeo</dd>
    <dd>Common</dd>
    <dd>Converge</dd>
    <dd>Crystal Castles</dd>
    <dd>Cursive</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>C</dt>
    <dd>Chromeo</dd>
    <dd>Common</dd>
    <dd>Converge</dd>
    <dd>Crystal Castles</dd>
    <dd>Cursive</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>E</dt>
    <dd>Explosions In The Sky</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>T</dt>
    <dd>Ted Leo & The Pharmacists</dd>
    <dd>T-Pain</dd>
    <dd>Thrice</dd>
    <dd>TV On The Radio</dd>
    <dd>Two Gallants</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>T</dt>
    <dd>Ted Leo & The Pharmacists</dd>
    <dd>T-Pain</dd>
    <dd>Thrice</dd>
    <dd>TV On The Radio</dd>
    <dd>Two Gallants</dd>
  </dl>
  <dl>
    <dt>T</dt>
    <dd>Ted Leo & The Pharmacists</dd>
    <dd>T-Pain</dd>
    <dd>Thrice</dd>
    <dd>TV On The Radio</dd>
    <dd>Two Gallants</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```